# How to Change the filename while exporting the HTML table to excel?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm using the below code for export the HTML table to excel file.Its working as per expectation.But the  excel file getting downloaded in the name of "download" always.I want to change the filename while download.

```
             var tableToExcel = (function() {
              var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
                , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
                , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
                , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
              return function(table, name) {
                if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
                window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
              }
            })()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following code to achieve the above requirement.

```
function tableToExcel(table, name) 
            {
            var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
                ,
                template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
                , base64 = function (s) {
                    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
                }
                , format = function (s, c) {
                    return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                        return c[p];
                    })
                }
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
            a.download = name+'.xls';
            //triggering the function
            a.click();
        }
```